# How dynamically set domainMax

Tags: vega-lite

How do I dynamically set y domainMax, I want the y axis value to be twice the maximum value, but domMax is a set value, I need to get an int number, any advice would be appreciated

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2021-03-01T00:00:00", "value": 1},
      {"date": "2021-04-01T00:00:00", "value": 3},
      {"date": "2021-05-01T00:00:00", "value": 2}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"calculate": "max(datum.value)+1", "as": "domMax"}],
  "params": [{"name": "domMax", "value": "domMax"}],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate":"max",
      "scale": {"domainMax": {"expr": "max(domMax)*2"}}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check out the documentation here:

- https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#pluck
- https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#extent
- https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#data

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2021-03-01T00:00:00", "value": 1},
      {"date": "2021-04-01T00:00:00", "value": 3},
      {"date": "2021-05-01T00:00:00", "value": 2}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {"name": "extents", "expr": "extent(pluck(data('source_0'), 'value'))"},
    {"name": "min", "expr": "extents[0]"},
    {"name": "max", "expr": "extents[1]*2"}
  ],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[min,max]"}}
    }
  }
}
```